# how to use the Container technology on Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, virtualization

Is there a way to deploy a distribution other than Ubuntu, as content on Ubuntu?

Say in my case i'm planning  a Redhat as a content on my Ubuntu 14.04 . If yes. How to do it?